# Getting simpleML to search further down through the page source

Tags: java, html, processing

I'm succeeding with reading [this site](http://tweetingtoohard.com/top) using [simpleML](http://www.learningprocessing.com/tutorials/simpleml/) in processing and getting the first username (which is babesmcphee) but I don't get the second username (which is JohnCMayer) or third, fourth, and so on. 
I'm not sure that I'm doing it right with the `Strings` or `html.indexOf`, I was thinking of doing a `for loop` and putting the usernames in an `array`.

Here's my code:

```
import simpleML.*;

void setup () {
 HTMLRequest req = new HTMLRequest(this,"http://tweetingtoohard.com/top");
req.makeRequest();
}

void netEvent(HTMLRequest answer) {
  String html = answer.readRawSource();    
  String link_filter = "/u/";  
  int first_link_start = html.indexOf(link_filter);  
  String link_filter_stop = "</a>";  
  int first_link_end = html.indexOf(link_filter_stop, first_link_start+3);  
  String real_link_end_filter = "\"";  
  int real_link_end = html.indexOf(real_link_end_filter, first_link_start);   
  String first_link = html.substring(first_link_start+3,real_link_end);  
  println(first_link);  
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "answer" contains the whole page, so you have to implement a loop to get all the names.

Like this:

```
public void netEvent(HTMLRequest answer) {
  String html = answer.readRawSource();

  int from = 0;
  int pos;
  while ((pos = html.indexOf("/u/", from)) != -1) {
    int end = html.indexOf("\"", pos);
    System.out.println(html.substring(pos + 3, end));
    from = html.indexOf("</a>", pos + 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed everything!